# fix the partition indexes OR fix ubuntu EFI

Tags: partitioning, gpt, grub-efi

I have a GPT partition table.
when i tried to repair the disk on my mac os x 10.9 it deleted the efi partition.
I already created it manually but i have a problem:
1- the efi partition instead of being at /dev/disk0s1 it became /dev/disk0s16. how can i reindex the partitions.
2- my linux partition was on /disk0s5 it became /disk0s4 that caused it not to boot. how can i change where to start at grub.efi
backup and repartition is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of any Linux or OS X repair tool that automatically deletes the EFI System Partition (ESP). More information on this is welcome, and [filing a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) is in order if it's a bug in a Linux tool. (Contact the software's publisher if it was a bug in OS X software that caused the problem.)

As to re-indexing partition numbers, the [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) program can do this. It's in the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu, or you can install the OS X version if you prefer. Use the `s` option on the main menu, then type `w` to save your changes. (You may also want to use `p` to view the partition table both before and after sorting the entries.) If the order was not sorted before or if it had gaps, you can use the `t` option on the experts' menu to transpose any two partitions (including empty entries), thus enabling you to create any ordering you like.

I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence; please clarify.

Comment: when i call the clover.efi file, it should boot linux from the partition. but the partition index had change which lead that it can't find kernal files